# Getting error : UNHANDLED REJECTION Reducers may not dispatch actions in react gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

suddenly it started giving me error : `UNHANDLED REJECTION Reducers may not dispatch actions`, when i try to run `npm start`, prior it was working fine for me, but somehow it started to giving me the error, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue, i am using `react` `gatsby`

Comment: You are probably dispatching something in your reducer.

Comment: Well reducers aren't meant to dispatch actions. Are you trying to do async stuff in your reducer? (Maybe add the code for the offending reducer)

Comment: i found the issue, it is issue of proxy of this code  proxy: {
     url: "http://1*****",
   },

Comment: Got it solved by upgrading [Gatsby](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25478#issuecomment-653207216)

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused due to a mismatch in your `gatsby-config` file from what is expected.
For example, if you use `SiteMetaData` instead of `SiteMetadata`, it won't show an error while rebuilding, but it can not be validated while re-running the application, and hence it will throw an error.
Refer to this documentation for more details about the [config api](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/)

Comment: The same happened to me in production after adding `flags` to the config file. However, the build was fine in the local env, but failed in production.
`flags: {
    DEV_SSR: false,
  },`